# Drive letter from URI type file path in C#

Tags: c#, filepath

What is the easiest way to get the drive letter from a URI type file path such as

```
file:///D:/Directory/File.txt
```

I know I can do (path here is a string containing the text above)

```
path = path.Replace(@"file:///", String.Empty);
path = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(path);
```

but it feels a bit clumsy. Is there a way to do it without using String.Replace or similar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var uri = new Uri("file:///D:/Directory/File.txt");
if (uri.IsFile)
{
    DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(uri.LocalPath);
    var driveName = di.Name; // Result: D:\\
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the following code:

```
    string path = "file:///D:/Directory/File.txt";
    if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) {
        Uri uri = new Uri(path);
        string actualPath = uri.AbsolutePath;
    }
```