# Opening a file by passing in absolute file path

Tags: c#

I'm currently storing a file path for a file I would like to open and read in for my program. However when I put that path into File.OpenText it adds the path to the current directory to the file path and then I get this error:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Users/km/Desktop/MP/file:/Users/km/Downloads/PT07E.obj".
```

The path I want is the one I am passing in, which is file:/Users/km/Downloads/PT07E.obj".

Is there a way to stop File.OpenText from adding to this path I am passing in originally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are operating with paths like `file:/{absolute path}` (which is actually an [`URI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier))
you may use [`System.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.113).aspx) class.
As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12685924/3872935).

```
var uri = new Uri("file:/Users/km/Downloads/PT07E.obj");
using (var reader = File.OpenText(uri.AbsolutePath))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! this appears to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a correct absolute path - that means, you forgot to define the drive (normally it's *C*). So your path would have to be (I'd use backslashes):

```
@"C:\Users\km\Downloads\PT07E.obj"
```

However it's a better idea not to use an absolute path for this. I'd use the specialFolder option of c#:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downlads", "PT07E.obj");
```

And it's always a good  idea to use `Path.Combine`, that uses the standard path splitter of the OS.

Comment: When I hardcode that into File.OpenText, I still get the same addition as before unfortunately

Comment: Are you getting the exactly same exception? Or does the file probably not even exist? But your exception actually is quite interesting - it says it couldn't find a *part* of the path and it couldn't find the *directory*. Please provide the new exception (if it's different) and the code you tried.

Comment: And make sure that you have permissions to access the folder

Comment: @Middleground3 so what exactly is your username? kmaune or km? The most plausible bug source is that you typed in a wrong directory name. Did you try the second method (with the special folder) I provided?

Comment: So now I am getting a FileNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/km/Desktop/MP/C:\Users\km\Downloads\PT07E.obj". I hardcoded your suggestion into File.OpenText() and the issue is it is still adding the path of the current directory to the path instead of just opening the file using the absolute path I am passing in it seems.

Comment: Actually I guess it adds the path because the drive C isn't existing on your machine. What is the drive you're operating with? Maybe use D instead. Or you may use, as suggested, the second solution, which (should) be independent of the drive letter.

Comment: I'm using a Mac if that helps, but it seems the issue is that no matter what path I put into File.OpenText(filepath) it adds the section "/Users/km/Desktop/MP/" in front of whatever filepath is. For example if I move the file "PT07E.obj" into the MP folder on my desktop and then use File.OpenText("PT07E.obj") everything works. However the issue is that for this application I cannot assume every file will be in the working directory for the user so I store the filepath when they upload their file and want to use that saved path to open it.

Comment: It's a huge difference wether you use a Mac, so it's very important - and actually I don't know how the filesystem works with macs. But `File.Open` should use the absolute path and not append it, at least if the entered path is valid.

Comment: Yea I don't know why `File.Open()` keeps appending to my file path being entered but that's definitely the issue and I can't figure it out for the life of me.