# File.OpenText is adding C:\ to the front which is an error

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to open a file, but for some reason it's putting C:\ in front of the server name, which is not correct.

I tried two different ways:

```
void ParseLogFile(string serverName, string logName)
{
   string lognameFull = logName + ".txt";
   string partialPath = @"\build\logs\";
   string combinedPath = "\\" + serverName + partialPath;
   string filePath = Path.Combine(combinedPath, Path.GetFileName(logNameFull)); 

   //one way:
   StreamReader reader0 = File.OpenText(@"\mach31\"); //error: 
   System.IO.FileNotFoundException : 
   Could not find file 'C:\mach31\ (even if there was a filename here it wouldn't find it with the C)

   //another way (moved cursor to run this and not the one above):
   StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath); //error: 
   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: '   Could not find a part of the path 
   'C:\mach31\build\logs\SpinFileVersionStats.txt'.'
}
```

So no matter what the filename is, it's putting C: in front of the string.  How do I prevent it from putting C there? I need the full path to our server, which doesn't have a C: in it.

I looked at [open file with full UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434711/opening-a-file-by-passing-in-absolute-file-path) I would think I wouldn't need to do what they are doing.
and also
[open file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=net-8.0)but I'm doing the same thing as they are, but they don't have a server name, they are using C:.

Any idea why it defaults to C: and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't you need to say `string combinedPath = @"\\" + serverName + partialPath;`?

Comment: `Path.Combine` can take several parts: maybe it would be better to use that than string concatenation.

Comment: When you are building a path, it tries to build an **absolute path**, get current directory which contains absolute path in it which starts with C:\, and then append your path to it. In windows it is required to provide an absolute path.

Comment: @EmperorEto I also tried \\ in front of servername . And in fact The combined path variable above does show the \\ in the code.

Comment: `"\\"` is a single backslash character.

Comment: In Windows, a single backslash in front of a path means: ["A relative path from the root of the current drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats). For example: "\temp" is the same as "C:\temp" (assuming you are on the C drive).

Comment: If path is not identified as [absolute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathfullyqualified?view=net-8.0) it is going to be treated as relative to the current working directory. If it starts with a backslash, the path is "rooted" and is treated as relative to the current working directory's drive. This is where `C:` is coming from.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried string filePath = Path.Combine("\\" ,serverName, partialPath, logNameFull); and I'm seeing it's dropping the servername  and adding C: so it has this error:  System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\build\logs\SpinFileVersionStats.txt'.'

Comment: @Michele print `filePath` or check its value in debugger.

Comment: @n0rd - I tried string filePath = Path.Combine("\\\\" ,serverName, partialPath, logNameFull); and it's showing filepath as filePath = "\\build\\logs\\SpinFileVersionStats.txt" and dropping the servername

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748032/why-does-path-combine-produce-this-result-with-a-relative-path

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it to work. Answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work with the uri method:

```
string serverPath = @"\\\\" + serverName;
string logNameFull = logName + ".txt";
string partialPath = @"\build\logs\";
string combinedPath2 = partialPath + logNameFull;
Uri serverUri = new Uri(serverPath + combinedPath2);
string finalPath = serverUri.LocalPath;

StreamReader readerb = File.OpenText(finalPath);
```